# Dividing an integer array into two equal sized sub-arrays?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across this question and couldn't find a reasonable solution.
How would you divide an unsorted integer array into 2 equal sized sub-arrays such that, difference between sub-array sums is minimum.

For example: given an integer array a[N] (unsorted), we want to split the array into be split into a1 and a2 where a1.length == a2.length i.e N/2 and (sum of all numbers in a1 - sum of all numbers in a2) should be minimum.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume all numbers are positve but there might be repetitions.

Comment: is the original array sorted? LOL

Comment: @SparKot okay, i'm not aware of that detail. Lets say unsorted.

Comment: Looks like you have pretty much the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). Although not an exact dupe, it looks like the answers to [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5717849/179910) probably apply here as well.

Comment: Can someone write code for [Differencing Algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Differencing_algorithm)?

Comment: as @JerryCoffin said that it's **partition problem** with a simple modification. I can add that the modification would be on the matter of `a1.length == a2.length` and that can be solved with getting the minimum numbers from the largest array and putting them in the other one till having the condition satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

While others have mentioned that this is a case of the partition problem with modification, I'd like to point out, more specifically, that it is actually a special case of the [minimum makespan problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) with two machines. Namely, if you solve the two-machine makespan problem and obtain a value `m`, you obtain the minimum difference `2*m - sum(i : i in arr)`

As the wikipedia article states, the problem is NP-complete for more than 2 machines. However, in your case, the [List scheduling algorithm](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~ptvu/ppds/lec7.pdf), which in general provides an 
approximate answer, is optimal and polynomial-time for the two-machine and three-machine case given a sorted list in non-increasing order.

[For details, and some more theoretical results on this algorithm, see here](http://books.google.com/books?id=i3S9_GnHZwYC&lpg=PA455&ots=nCltodIuOy&dq=graham%20list%20scheduling%20algorithm&pg=PA455#v=onepage&q=graham%20list%20scheduling%20algorithm&f=false).